# a question about singularity in numerical calculation

Tags: differential-equations, singularity

Suppose I want to numerically calculate a PDE as following
$$a\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}f(x)+\frac{b}{x}\frac{\partial }{\partial x}f(x)+c=0, x\in (-1, 1)$$
where $a$, $b$, $c$ are constants.
So basically, the PDE has a singularity at $x=0$. Now since I don't know the principle behind the numerical calculations. I wonder, can I avoid the singularity simply by multiplying $x$ at both sides, namely
$$ax\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}f(x)+b\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x }+cx=0?$$

Comment: Note that either way `f[x] -> (x (-c x + (2 a (a + b) x^(-(b/a)) C[1])/(a - b)))/(
  2 (a + b)) + C[2]`

Comment: You seem to ask about solving an ODE numerically but accepted an answer that solve it symbolically. The question and answer seem unrelated, except that they are about the same ODE. Please clarify.  Is the question how to solve this ODE, or about how numerical solvers work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might expect: the solution itself has a singularity at $x=0$.

Solving either PDE gives the same solution:

```
DSolve[a x D[f[x], x, x] + b D[f[x], x] + c x == 0, f[x], x]
```

> {{f[x] -> (x (-> c x + (2 a (a + b) x^(-(b/a)) C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCJgH.png))/(a - b)))/(2 (a + b)) + C[2]}}

The function has the form:

[image]

Which, as you can see has no value for $x=0$.

I wouldn't normally be so quick to multiply out the $x$, but in this case it's possible.